# confusion with jquery form action spring mvc thymeleaf

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

i have a form where i set the action with a button click. on submitting the form, i send the data to the controller, which handles the data and goes back to the page.

e.g.

i start with http://localhost/test ... put in some data, click the button, the data will be send to http://localhost/ablehnen and now i'm on http://localhost/ablehnen in the browser. if i click the button again, the browser goes to http://localhost/ablehnen/ablehnen which is wrong! can anybody tell me, why i go to http://localhost/ablehnen/ablehnen ??? how can i fix this problem?

```
<form id="theForm"  class="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator" method="POST" role="form"  th:object="${intProvDefApproval}">
...
</from>

<button type="button" id="ablehnen" class="btn btn-danger" th:text="#{ablehnen}"></button>


$("#ablehnen").click(function() {
$("#theForm").prop( 'action', "ablehnen");
$("#theForm").submit();
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code from your controller? What does the function ablehnen do? The controller is responsible for your url change.

Comment: `@RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String test(@ModelAttribute("intProvDefApproval") IntProvDef4Approval intProvDefApproval,
            Model model, Locale locale) {
        return ("templates/edit");

    }`

...

  `@RequestMapping(path = "/ablehnen", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String ablehnen(@ModelAttribute("intProvDefApproval") IntProvDef4Approval intProvDefApproval,
            Model model, Locale locale) {
        return ("templates/edit");

    }`

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you the click event is fired, the string 'ablehnen' gets added at the end of your action. try setting the attribute action="ablehnen" in the form itself not from the jquery. See below

```
<form id="theForm"  class="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator" method="POST" action="ablehnen" role="form"  th:object="${intProvDefApproval}">
```

...

Comment: the problem is, that i have more than one button on the page with different actions. so i can not set it in the form

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try using relative path with respect to root.
$("#theForm").prop( 'action', "/ablehnen");
or 
root_path = "http://localhost"
action_path = root_path + "/ablehnen"

$("#theForm").prop( 'action', action_path);

Regards,
Krishan

Answer (score 0):

i found the bug ... i have forgotten the mapping of the controller ... the controller has a additionl mapping @RequestMapping("/myController") .. but i have no idea why it works at the first klick without any error

correct is:

```
$("#theForm").prop( 'action', "/myController/ablehnen");
```